# Google analytics with multiple accounts and properties doesn't show data for all propertes in both Google Analytics API and the web console

Tags: javascript, google-analytics, google-analytics-api

I am using Google Analytics JS API to access the data. When I have multiple properties and multiple accounts the data only shows up for the first few sites not for the later ones. Even after 24 hours its very flaky, shows up sometimes but not others. This not the case with the API but in the console as well.

When I hit the websites attached to the property it shows in the tracker view that data is being sent but the same doesn't show in realtime console.

Any info is appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: The fact that you are using the API seems irrelevant - as per your second paragraph you have a problem with data collection. Check the account ids in the tracking calls (is data being sent to the correct property? ) and check for over-zealous filtering in your data views.

Comment: I can see the data collection happening in the web sites. The tracking ids match the calls and for the filtering I have tried without filtering as well in the query explorer but to the same results

Comment: Your questions is not entirely clear to me.  But in the end it sounds like you are saying your calls to the API are not coming back with the expected results.  If this is the case, have you tried the queries using the query explorer: https://ga-dev-tools.appspot.com/query-explorer/

Comment: Yep I tried that too.
to be clear my problem lies when I have many properties, the data from all  the sites go to Google but it doesn't show up in the Google analytics page/ query explorer/ analytics API. 
In all the three I am not using filters to see the data and the reporting call for each property(site) is sending the data to Google.